# What is the exact meaning for firebase crash issue VC.editPayment(indexValue:sectionValue:) + 4379007756. What this line no. indicates

Tags: ios, firebase

I know this is a conceptual rather than codebase, however not getting the solutions for this I put this......

Recently I have fixed many issues that reported from firebase for iOS App. However in certain cases I have found that some issues are showing the exact line number and some not showing exact. If the line no is not exact it will become a little problematic for debugging.

Here is the code snippet:

```
closure #2 in closure #1 in 
VC.editPayment(indexValue:sectionValue:) + 4379007756
```

In my file I don't have such lines of code, not understand what it means to say by compiler...

[image]

It will be appreciated if anyone can provide a clue on this.